# Access JSON results of Python script executed on SQL server 2017

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server

I have a Python script which outputs JSON that I would like to be able to manipulate in SQL Server.

The Python script runs as expected in VS Code and I have also been able to get the script to run on SQL server using the `sp_execute_external_script` stored procedure as below but this just prints the JSON as text in the result window.

How do I modify the following code to so I can get `personJson` back to SQL so I can then perform commands on it such as `OPENJSON()` etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**SQL/Python**

```
execute sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import json

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "New York"
}

personJson = json.dumps(x)

print(personJson)'
```

**Desired Result**

```
select * 
from openjson(personJson) --Where personJson comes from the Python script
with
(
    PersonName varchar(50) '$.name'
    , PersonAge int '$.age'
    , City varchar(50) '$.city'
)
```

| PersonName | PersonAge | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 30 | New York |

**Additional Info**

- SQL Server 2017
- Python 3.5.2

Comment: Do you want to take the variable directly from the python script ? Why don't you import the json file as string data ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `[powerbi]`?

Comment: Have you read the [sp_execute_external_script (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql) documentation yet? Seems like you'd want to make use of the `@output_data_1_name` parameter to return the JSON inside a Pandas data frame.

Comment: @AlexisOlson apologies, my full python script returns values from the Power BI API, but I realised that information isn't relevant to the answer and bloated my question, so I removed all the unnecessary information but forgot to remove the tag.